# How to read a musical file using python and identify the various frequency levels of the notes?

Tags: python

please help me with the python...this is my project topic...

Comment: Same person? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610599/

Comment: Define "musical file" so duffymo and I can stop arguing.

Comment: oh well no....my batchmate...we are supposed to do this together..

Comment: how can i define it? what i meant is what you think....its a continuous time series of varying amplitudes...

Comment: No reema, this is your problem, not ours.  If it's a continuous time series of varying amplitudes, go read about FFT.  SciPy/NumPy will have a nice FFT implementation all ready to go - unless your assignment is to write an FFT implementation.  Good luck.

Comment: Is it MIDI, WAV, MP3, WMA, some file format your teacher made up for this assignment, ...?

Comment: @mbeckish....WAV file...the teacher just suggested it...

@duffymo...did you mean to give me a link for "FFT. SciPy/NumPy" ...i guess that's exactly what i need now...

The real project topic is to identify the musical instruments played in a sound file(say wav file) which contains a variety of instruments...this is the first time I came across a topic dealing with DSP...i just have some basic knowledge about DSP and FFT...i have searched a lot on this topic...and could not find any satisfying results...So thought of asking here...please do help me with it...

Comment: The first task to be done now is, to separate the wav file components based on ther frequency levels and store them as different wav files(using scipy)...ie the code has to read the wav file , perform fft on it...and the components with same frequency is stored in a new wav file....so there will be multiple wav files as output...any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[Fourier transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).  Learn some basics about music and signals before even considering code.

### Basic Outline:

#### Audio Import

See http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/ and find one that will import your (unspecified) file.

#### Analysis

Get [`numpy`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/).

```
>>> from numpy.fft import fft
>>> a = abs(fft([1,2,3,2]*4))
>>> a
array([ 32.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   8.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   8.,   0.,   0.,   0.])
```

We can clearly see the DC component at 0, then the major AC component at `fs/4` and `3*fs/4` due to this being a real signal, as all frequency components are mirrored over the X-axis.

Comment: i know it is to be done by applying FFT...just got a vague idea about the conversion also...but i need code urgently...

Comment: No, you don't need FFT for pure tones.  See my answer.  And don't ask for code - that's your job.

Comment: @duffymo - How do you know if FFT is needed or not, when the file format has not been specified?

Comment: I don't know, because the file format has not been specified.  But then neither do you.  We've both staked out our positions: mine is pure tone, yours is continuous time series of amplitudes.

Comment: well its not a pure tone...n of course FFT is needed...

Comment: thank you duffymo...but if it was a pure tone...how wud it have been done?could you please tell me dat?

Comment: Not until you provide more details, reema.  Go do your own homework.

Comment: ok just tell me what all details u need....i have tried a lot myself...nothing worked...if you could help me with it...

Comment: @reema Updated answer.  1) import audio, 2) run FFT

Comment: @Nick T...could u give me a solution for this, without using audiolab?