# How to read wav file using scipylab in Python?

Tags: python, scipy

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Proper grammar ("u"? Seriously?) and a **real** question would help us help you, but this is just an insult.

Comment: You know, I don't expect he'll get an answer, but that "u" was hurting my eyes.

Comment: **SciPy** + (Matplotlib => Mat **LAB**) = Scipylab?

Comment: There's been a rash of new users trying to do stuff with audio in python lately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615686/how-to-get-frequency-samples-from-a-given-wav-file-using-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610847/how-to-read-a-musical-file-using-python-and-identify-the-various-frequency-levels

Answer (score 5):

I can't find any wave functionality in [`scipylab`](https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/browser/SciPyLab/trunk?rev=22002), but that's OK, you can add it!

```
import scipylab
import wave

scipylab.wave = wave
del wave
```

The documentation for scipylab's wave functions can then be found here: http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html.  Be sure to prefix them all with `scipylab.` though.

```
mysound = scipylab.wave.open('mywav.wav','r')
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a built-in module: [`wave`](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html). Or a [SciPy function](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.io.wavfile.html#read)!

Comment: What if he/she really wants to do it using scipylab, whatever that is?

Comment: @Deniz Dogan: Hmm, well, some Googling suggests that it's a numerical computation library: https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/browser/EPDLab/trunk/enthought/epdlab?rev=23256. I suspect we'll get more details shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use scipylab to read WAV files, python provides the [wave](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html) module for this task.

Comment: but i need to use scipylab.since it is one of the specifications mentioned in my project

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided more information in your question about what you are trying to do and what the requirements are.